# iAds not displaying in test apps even though i joined iAd Network?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, iad, banner-ads

This is frustrating beyond reason. I am unable to view a single test advertisment on my device or on the simulator.

> To enable ads from the iAd App Network in your app, simply do the following in iTunes Connect:
>
> Agree to the iAd App Network Contract. Complete the required tax forms
>   and, if you have not already done so, set up your banking information.
>   Enable your app for iAd rich media ads in the Manage Your Applications
>   module.

Done and Done as you can see from the following screenshots [image: bank tax contact forms] [image: iAd advertising enabled]

I have also linked my project to the `iAd Framework` and imported `<iAd/iAd.h>` and in `viewDidLoad` i put `self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;`

What am I doing wrong? Does someone know from experience what is happening? Is there some sort of little hack because I could not have followed the steps more cautiously. Thankyou

Comment: Have you set your view as a delegate to iAds and are getting callbacks to the ads loaded successfully vs. failed to load?